# How do I make the menu bar opaque when invoking the Dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, panel

This is an experiment with Unity. Everybody tried to make top panel in Unity transparent. I don't. I want to make top panel always opaque, even when the Dash is open. Is it possible? Or are the Dash and transparent menu bar united?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not possible. Once the Dash is open, Unity is programmed to make the panel transparent and the icons white.

You could suggest an alternative behavior in a bug report.